# How to make API call with Typescript-Angular Client generated with Swagger-Codegen

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to make an API call with the Client Typescript-Angular API library generated via Swagger Codegen, without success. I don't understand if I'm wrong with calls or if the library has some problems.

I try to explain what I have done:

1. I have generated the library with Swagger Codegen 2.4.13-SNAPSHOT with the following script:

> ```
> java -jar C:\path\to\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i  C:\path\to\swagger.json -l typescript-angular -o c:\path\to\client-lib -c c:\config.json
> ```

Swagger.json is an OpenAPI 2.0 document and config.json look like this:

```
 {  
   "npmName": "my-ts-angular-client",
   "npmVersion":"1.0.1",
   "ngVersion":"6.0.0",
   "withInterfaces": true,
   "supportsES6": true
 }
```

My authentication scheme is 'Bearer Authentication' and it is the only security definition.

2. I published the library on my registry, following the auto-generated readme file, like this:

> ```
> npm install
> npm run build
> npm publish dist
> ```

3. I installed the client in my angular project and the configured it in app.module.ts as suggested:

   ```
    // configuring providers and base path
     import { ApiModule, Configuration, ConfigurationParameters, BASE_PATH } from 'my-ts-angular-client';

    export function apiConfigFactory (): Configuration {
      const params: ConfigurationParameters = {
        accessToken: "xxxxx" //Passed directly for testing purposes
      }
      return new Configuration(params);
    }

    @NgModule({
        imports: [ ApiModule.forRoot(apiConfigFactory) ],
        declarations: [ AppComponent ],
        providers: [{provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'https://my-rest-api.com/v1'}],
        bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
   ```
4. So I tried to make a call:

   ```
      export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private userServ: UsersService, private apiModule: ApiModule) { }

      ngOnInit() {

          this.userServ.userResourceGetUserByIdGet("userIdTest","response").
          subscribe (user=> {
          console.log(user.body);
          });
      }
   ```

The server returns a response with status 403.
I went to see what happens on the server side, and I noticed that in the request headers there is no "Authorization" field (I checked on the browser and here in the request headers there is actually the "Authorization" field).

In addition, a CORS error is shown on the browser, but I think it is an oversight of the browser, because on the server side I have:

> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"

Am I wrong with the API call?
Maybe I need to specify the authentication method? How?

Thank you.